# How to change UINavigationBar background color from clear to red when user scrolls down in the table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar

I have a table view and a navigation bar in front of it.
I want that when user scrolls down the background color of the navigation bar starts to change from clear to red, like increasing alpha.

Problem for me is that when user scroll down when navigation bar background alpha will be 1.0 the user can still see behind the navigation bar!

Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.mainProfileTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-44,0,0,0);


    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isOpaque = true
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 180/255, green: 40/255, blue: 56/255, alpha: 1.0)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(red: 180/255, green: 40/255, blue: 56/255, alpha: 1.0)


    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named : "navigationBarBackGround"), for: .default)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 180/255, green: 40/255, blue: 56/255, alpha: 1.0)

}
```

and here is the method that detect user is scrolling Up or Down

```
var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0


func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        // moved to top
        print("move Up\(scrollView.contentOffset.y)")
        print("alpha\(Float(scrollView.contentOffset.y / 166))")
        navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = scrollView.contentOffset.y / 166

    } else if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        // moved to bottom

        navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = scrollView.contentOffset.y / 166
        print("alpha\(Float(scrollView.contentOffset.y / 166))")
        print("move down\(scrollView.contentOffset.y)")

    } else {

        // didn't move
    }
}
```

Comment: Set `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false` to remove transparency from navigation bar

Comment: I set that But the background color will be going to black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can it be that the navigation bar is **translucent**?
Like this:

[image]

Change it using:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = False
```

And remove:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage...
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Then modify the `barTintColor` when user scrolls.

Comment: I changed that But when I use this the background of navigation Bar will be going to black

Comment: I modified my answer, please check

Comment: doesn't changed when I used this

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help But I should use translucent false in the scroll View Did Change Method So the answer is this

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
    // moved to top
    print("move Up\(scrollView.contentOffset.y)")
    print("alpha\(Float(scrollView.contentOffset.y / 166))")
    navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = scrollView.contentOffset.y / 166
    if Float(scrollView.contentOffset.y / 166) >= 1.0 {

            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

            }

} else if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
    // moved to bottom

    navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = scrollView.contentOffset.y / 166
    print("alpha\(Float(scrollView.contentOffset.y / 166))")
    print("move down\(scrollView.contentOffset.y)")

} else {

    // didn't move
}
}
```